# Move photos to a new iPhone without iCloud

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore, photos.app

I've got 24GB of photos on an iPhone 8 Plus that I'd like to move to an iPhone X. Normally, I believe I can just backup on iTunes and restore to the new device. Unfortunately, I am on iOS 12.3.2, which is available only for iPhone 8 Plus.

I tried to restore to iPhone X, but it said I need to update iOS, iOS 12.3.2 is not available for any other device.

I looked at downgrading the iPhone 8 Plus back to 12.3.1, but I do not have access to a 12.3.1 backup from which to restore photos.

Are there any other options for cloning the camera roll between iPhones? (I'd prefer not to use iCloud because it's 24GB of data).

NOTE: I have tried to import photos from the iphone to the MacOS photos app,  but that is not an exact clone of the cameraroll. My 'Favorites' tags did not transfer. Has this changed recently?

Comment: Do you have access to a Mac/PC computer?

Comment: yes, I have iTunes on a Mac with plenty of storage and a 12.3.2 backup

Comment: An unconventional approach you may take is to transfer all the photos and videos using Photos or Image Capture app to your Mac from iPhone 8 Plus. They transfer them over to your iPhone X. You can also AirDrop them from iPhone 8 Plus to iPhone X, but it would be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: I believe the last time I imported photos to the MacOS Photos app, the `favorites` tags did not transfer.  I'd like to keep them

Comment: Test if AirDrop retains the favorites tag?

Comment: AirDrop will lose the favorites tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify some value, you can restore the high version backup to the lower version device, it is usually work in minor version updates.
First of all, open the device backup folder in finder and **quit itunes**, you can see a file name Info.plist. Get a plist editor e.g xcode, change the `Product Version` 12.3.2 to 12.3.1 `Build Version` 16F250 to 16F203, save the file then you can restore it to iPhone X.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii I have used this method twice and succeeded(11.2 to 11.0.3 and 12.1 to 12.0). This is obviously not a normal method that is 100% work. But if you copy a backup, there is no risk to the original iPhone 8 Plus. And 12.3.1 to 12.3.2 just fix a camera problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install Google Photos app from the App Store on both iPhones. Sync all your photos and there you have it in your new iPhone X.

Comment: Syncing favourites still remain a problem. Quality of photos another, assuming OP has basic Drive storage,  or limited internet bandwidth.